# What is a commandline utility to shorten input?

Tags: command-line

what's a commandline tool to take input from stdin, remove the first X character, and place the output to stdout?

Similar to how tail can skip the X lines and display the rest, but for characters on each line instead of lines in each file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cut` command might fit your needs:

```
echo "1234567890" | cut -c 6-
```

Outputs:

```
67890
```

Comment: Oh, that does work - I read through the man page, and it didn't say you could leave off `FILE`, so I assumed this wouldn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Square brackets generally mean optional arguments, if you do not specify a file it reads standard input. :)

Comment: Oh!  I hadn't noticed the brackets until you pointed them out.  Thanks!!!